Как получить список тем (ветки, топики, треды) из группы Telegram?
Требуется получить списком все созданные ветки в группе Telegram по API. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это сделать?

Если вы имели в виду темы в телеграмм форуме, то не подскажу как их достать через API, но можно вручную, достаточно просто скопировать ссылку на тему, и последние цифры это и будет ID вашей темы.
156 в данном случае - это ID темы:
https://t.me/c/*********/156 


Спасибо за ответ! Но хотелось бы знать как это сделать через API
